# why make: execvp: device/coo: Permission denied

Tags: makefile

In current directory:

```
.
├── android
├── build
│   └── Makefile
├── device
│   ├── coo
│   │   └── AndroidProducts.mk
│   ├── google
│   │   └── AndroidProducts.mk
│   └── sky
│       └── AndroidProducts.mk
├── kernel
├── product
└── vendor
    ├── coo
    └── sky
        └── AndroidProducts.mk
```

Makefile:

```
  5 define _search-android-products-files-in-dir
  6 $(sort $(shell test -d $(1) && find -L $(1) \
  7   -maxdepth 6 \
  8   -name .git -prune \
  9   -o -name AndroidProducts.mk -print))
 10 endef
 11 
 12 define _find-android-products-files
 13 $(foreach d, device vendor product, $(call _search-android-products-files-in-dir, $(d))) \
 14   build/product/AndroidProducts.mk
 15 endef
 16 
 17 
 18 define _get_directories
 19 $(foreach f, $(_find-android-products-files), $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(f))))
 20 endef
 21 
 22 .PHONY: all search find dir
 23 
 24 all: search find
 25 
 26 search:
 27         $(call _search-android-products-files-in-dir,device)
 28 
 29 
 30 find:
 31         $(_find-android-products-files)
 32 
 33 dir:
 34         $(_get_directories)
```

make the target *find* is ok:

```
$ make -f build/Makefile find
device/coo/AndroidProducts.mk device/google/AndroidProducts.mk device/sky/AndroidProducts.mk  vendor/sky/AndroidProducts.mk   build/product/AndroidProducts.mk
```

but make the target *dir* have error:

$ make -f build/Makefile dir
device/coo  device/google  device/sky  vendor/sky  build/product
make: execvp: device/coo: Permission denied
make: *** [dir] Error 127

Why the error:
make: execvp: device/coo: Permission denied

Comment: Does `dir device/coo` work in terminal?

Comment: What do you expect the `dir` rule to do? What do you expect `$(_get_directories)` to be?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the formatting of the example output.  It's very confusing all run together in a single line.